# accessing JSON value if key is array element

Tags: javascript, json

suppose i receive JSON object from the server as this

```
{ "asdf[zxcv]": "qwer" }
```

how do i access `asdf`, `zxcv`, and `qwer` in javascript, so i can use the object this way ?

```
theobj.asdf[zxcv] = 'qwer'
```

Comment: You need to create key string grammatically and then you can access the value of it.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to access `zxcv`? That doesn't make sense unless you're contemplating an ES6 WeakMap or something.

Comment: In your example `zxcv` is not a variable but an associative key of `asdf`.

Comment: sorry, my intention was not clear. i edited just now to clear the confusion. i need to access the array name `asdf`, the index `zxcv`, and the value `qwer`. and not by string/regex parsing, please

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation is not in the JSON RFC. You can only read it as string.

```
var simpleObj = {
  "simpleKey": "simpleValue"
}

console.log(simpleObj)

var advObj = {
  "advKey[1]": "advValue"
}

console.log(JSON.parse(advObj)); // SyntaxError 
console.log(advObj.advKey[1]) // TypeError
console.log(advObj["advKey[1]"]) // can only read as string
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to *refactor* the source JSON into something more meaningful so you can access the values in regular JavaScript way.

Run the following snippet to check how you can solve the issue:

```js
var x = '{ "asdf[zxcv]": "qwer" }';
var y = JSON.parse(x);

var result = Object.keys(y).reduce(function(result, key) {
  var parentKey = key.substring(0, key.indexOf("["));
  var innerKey = /[a-z]+\[([a-z]+)\]/i.exec(key)[1];

  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key))
    result[parentKey] = {};

  result[parentKey][innerKey] = y[key];

  return result;
}, {});

document.getElementById("structure").textContent = JSON.stringify(result);

var zxcv = result["asdf"]["zxcv"];

document.getElementById("someValue").textContent = zxcv;
```

```html
<h2>Refactored data structure as nested objects:</h2>
<div id="structure"></div>

<h2>Accessing some value: result["asdf"]["zxcv"] or result.asdf.zxcv</h2>
<div id="someValue"></div>
```

It's all about creating nested objects to represent the associative keys in the source JSON properties representing a conceptual associative array...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to access all elements without reconstructing object.

```
   jQuery.each(JSON.parse('{ "asdf[zxcv]": "qwer" }'), function(index, value) {
  var i = index;// i = "asdf[zxcv]"
  var v = value;// v = "qwer"
  var iOfInnerValue = (/\[(.*?)\]/g).exec(i)[1];// innerValue = "zxcv"
   var iOfOuterValue = index.replace("["+(/\[(.*?)\]/g).exec(i)[1]+"]",""); // outerValue = "asdf"

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to assign the data to a variable and then you can use Object keys to get the key which is the part before the `:`. Here's an example.

```
var j = { "asdf[zxcv]": "qwer" };

console.log(Object.keys(j)); //["asdf[zxcv]"]
console.log(j); //{asdf[zxcv]: "qwer"}
```